# Why does my select menu show up padded on my actual phone but not my chrome phone emulator?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I have an flask app that generates the following select box:

```
<select id="ptype1-select" name="ptype1-select">
  <option value="">--select--</option>
  <option value="normal">normal</option>
  <option value="fire">fire</option>
  <! –– several more options here ––>
</select>
```

When I look at this select box on my Samsung S8 android in Chrome, the options are very padded.  However when I render using the android emulator build into Chrome on my laptop, the options are not padded.  When I use CSS to alter the padding of the options, the CSS changes I make are reflected in the emulator on my laptop, but not in the android itself.

Why does the select box look so different on an android as opposed to in an android emulator?  Is there a way I can reduce the padding that appears on the android?

On Samsung S8 Android on Chrome

[image: Android select menu]

On Android Emulator option in Chrome on Laptop

[image: Emulator select menu]

Comment: what happens if you tell Android Chrome to display the page as `desktop site`?

Comment: select option has different implementation on each device, go to iphone and it will have a different representation

Comment: @jsotola The select popup looks exactly the same when I display as a desktop site on Android Chrome.

Comment: @Berto99 - so do you think this mean there is no way to use CSS to adjust the padding of my select options?

Comment: as DOM element yes, but not the list that the browser shows when you click it (you can use JS libraries to create dropdown lists that looks like this, but built with divs , labels and so)